# emacs evil when shell command returns error message it is inserted in main buffer

Tags: shell, vim, emacs, buffer

I use emacs evil.
I have encountered the following error:

I select a visual block using Shift + v
then I want to execute an external command on a selected block, so I press ":", then "!" and type command "column -t"

```
:'<,'>!column -t
```

When i enter external command correctly - everything is fine -  text is divided into columns. But sometimes I can mistype a command and the error message replaces the selected text right in my opened file.
(for example I mysype :'<,'>!columnt)

So instead of my selected block I get

```
zsh:1: command not found: columnt
```

When I try emacs way of executing external command over a selected block with M-! and do a typo - error message appears in buffer *messages*. I consider it a correct behavior.

Is there a way to make errors of external command called from evil to be displayed in *messages* too?

To be clear - my .emacs contains only 3 following lines:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/evil")
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, that's exactly what Vim does too so, considering the whole point of evil is to be an exhaustive vi[m] emulation, I'd say that the behavior is correct. You should try [their issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues).

Comment: True, vim does so too. But this why emacs is better - I believe this can be changed in emacs!

Comment: Hence my suggestion to use their issue tracker. Also, see the end of the "Bug reports" section in https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/wiki/Home